# Conda doesn't recognize package updated by PIP and link error(337)

Tags: pip, conda

Recently I use `conda update --all` to update all packages. But there is an error:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::wheel-0.30.0-py_1'.
```

So I update wheel by pip. After that I use `conda update --all` again while the error still remains. It looks like that conda doesn't know that the version of wheel has been 0.30 so that there is no need to install it.

Comment: That's correct. Conda does not manage packages installed (or upgraded) by pip. Is there any other error text?

Comment: It looks like that packages of conda and pip has different install folders. So i use pip-review to update all packages. The link error of conda is too annoyed.

Comment: Im getting the same error with you on windows 64bit (both 2.7 and 3.6 py) when doing conda upgrade --all. Any workarounds?

Comment: I have tried multi-hours on conda upgrade --all in vain. So far pip-review --interactive is the best solution.